# excel vba workday function

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA world. I recently run into a dumb question regarding application.worksheetfunction.workday.

I did a few research on it, all people are suggesting that using "application.workday" or "application.worksheetfunction.workday" instead of "worksheet.workday". But neither of them work for me.

Here's my coding, I want to auto-fill a textbox in my userform based on value entered in other textbox.

```
If xDateValidation(xTran.Text) = True Then
    xTran.Text = Format(xTran.Text, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    Debug.Print Format(Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(xTran.Text, 2), "dd/mm/yyyy")
    xSettlement.Text = Format(Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(xTran.Text, 2), "dd/mm/yyyy")
Else
    xTran.Text = ""
End If
```

My coding comes back with below error message. This error message appears as well when i replace "Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay" with "WorksheetFunction.WorkDay".
[Error Message on WorksheetFunction.WorkDay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P12oq.jpg)

If i change my code to "Application.WorkDay" then, below message would appear.
[Error Message on Application.WorkDay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eH11.jpg)

Can anyone please help me out with it? If there anything wrong with my coding or setting?

Comment: The xDateValidation is a function to return true and false on value entered in textbox. It tests if the value entered full fills my requirements on date

Comment: `Application.Workday` is for adding a number of working days to the **date** provided. It needs a DATE, not a STRING.

Comment: It works! thanks HEAPS CLR!

Answer (score 0):

You could alter all of your code to treat xTran as a date in the first place and perform the WorkDay function upon it, or simply alter your code to convert the string back to a date as part of it like so:

```
xSettlement.Text = Format(Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(DateValue(xTran.Text), 2), "dd/mm/yyyy")
```